# Puppeteer - Using page.select() when the ID starts with a digit

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to select an option in this dropdown list.

```
<select id="2a08e407-30aa-4c0f-9786-d94246cc524c" name="hours">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
</select>
```

I've tried doing it as followed.

```
await page.select('#2a08e407-30aa-4c0f-9786-d94246cc524c', '00']);
```

But it fails.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#308091e2-9283-4663-9e87-5fb1137fb433' is not a valid selector.
```

**I think this is because the ID starts with a digit.** How could I solve this?

Some more details:

- This ID is generated every time I'm loading the page (so it's different at each run). I'm extracting it every time I'm loading the page with the following:

```
const selectorHour = (await page.$x(
   "//select[@name='hours']"
))[0];
const idSelectorHour = await (await selectorHour.getProperty('id')).jsonValue();
await page.select('#' + idSelectorHour, '00']);
```

- I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the fact it starts with a digit, because every time the ID starts with a letter, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: No, that's fine it's just an attribute it can be anything in theory; that ID however is a UUID is it being generated uniquely each page load and so it's not existing next call? Have you examined the source to confirm?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK indeed, it's a unique ID. I'm getting it every time I'm loading the page. I'm updating my post so it contains this additional information.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK FYI I'm pretty sure it's due to the fact it starts with a digit. When the ID starts with a letter, my code works. It only fails when it starts with a digit.

Comment: So as mentioned by Traynor, do attribute selector it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's because number is not a valid CSS selector.

Try attribute selector:

```
await page.select(`[id="${idSelectorHour}"]`, '00');
```